# How to remove a comma from a token using a Custom TokenFilter in Lucene.net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, lucene, lucene.net

I have a custom tokenfilter setup to parse keywords such as

```
oracle,java,sybase,vb.net etc.
```

into

```
oracle java sybase vb.net
```

and it's working fine, however one of the test docs has the following text

```
,oracle java,sybase,unix
```

and i'm trying to remove the leading COMMA from

```
,oracle
```

using the code below

```
    public override bool IncrementToken()
    {
        if (!input.IncrementToken())
            return false;


        char[] buffer = termAtt.TermBuffer();
        int bufferLength = termAtt.TermLength();

...
        else if (bufferLength > 1 && buffer[0] == ',')
        {
            // strip the starting , off !
            offsetAtt.SetOffset(offsetAtt.StartOffset + 1, offsetAtt.EndOffset);
        // where offsetAtt = AddAttribute<IOffsetAttribute>();
        }
        ...

        return true;

    }
```

however that does not remove the comma

any help on how to make this work ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tokens in Lucene work based on attributes, i.e. each property of a token (like text value, offset, etc) is an attribute.

The text value of a token is associated with the token TermAttribute.class.

Once you change the offset and other properties, you may also have to change the text it self, probably using the following snippet.

```
private final TermAttribute termAtt; // instance variable

termAtt = addAttribute(TermAttribute.class); // initialization in constructor 

....


 else if (bufferLength > 1 && buffer[0] == ',')
        {

            // strip the starting , off !
            offsetAtt.SetOffset(offsetAtt.StartOffset + 1, offsetAtt.EndOffset);

        // update the termAtt
            termAtt.setTermBuffer("sub-content of the buffer");

        }

....
```

Let me know whether it worked..